# Online resource recommendation for learning about vector analysis

Tags: vector-fields

In the last semester I had *Vector Analysis* lecture. We have seen about some basic geometry of sphere, then we got into basics if vectors that we seen in first semester in mechanics lecture but this was more like linear algebra. Then I learned about lines and planes. Then we have seen about partial derivative, double integrals, triple integrals, scalar field, vector field, gradient vector, divergence of a scalar and vector fields, rotations of vector fields, curl of vector fields, line integrals and so on.

Due to covid-19 I couldn't be able to learn and understand the topics I have seen in the lecture. Also I'm interested in these divergence, curl, rotation and vector fields topics. I want to learn them all from zero. I need your online resource recommendation. If you can recommend me PDF file, it could be very helpful. (I like demonstrations and illustrations of vector analysis. If the PDF has good illustrations, I would be very happy)

Comment: This would be better suited to MathSE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know two good courses on this topic that could help you to visualize the demonstrations and illustrate them. A good start is the ***Vector Calculus for Engineers*** available on [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/learn/vector-calculus-engineers). The other one is the ***Multivariable Calculus*** available on [Mit opencourseware](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-02-multivariable-calculus-fall-2007/). Both of them will give you the tools that you are looking for.

Comment: Does this MIT OCW course has good geometric illustrations? I know It's a weird question but I would like to see things in visual way.

Comment: Yes, this is why I recommended the lectures instead of PDF's. It might help you to visualize better than in a book.  My suggestion is to watch a lecture about one of those topics that you mention and see whether it works for you.

Comment: Yes, I actually watched a part of a video about Line Integrals. The teacher seems to be teaching very well. Thanks for the recommendation! I think I solved the problem :)

Comment: By the way, both links give me the same course. Is it right?

Comment: No, sorry! I've just edited the answer with the correct link. Thanks to pointed out.

Comment: Alright, thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two webs I think could help you.1. http://zh.b-ok.org 2. http://en.bookfi.net/

You can search a lot of books you want.